# How to maintain unique values in database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have attribute table with attribute type and value field.

```
AttrType      --     AttrValue
----------------------------------
attr1       --       value1
attr2       --       value2
attr3       --       value3
attr1       --       value1
```

I need to make sure that attribute type 'attr1' must have unique values.
Like above value1 is repeated for attr1 which I need to avoid.

Is there any database level check that I can add on table?

Comment: Add constraint `unique(AttrType,  AttrValue)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a unique constraint to your table:

```
alter table tablename add constraint constraintname unique(AttrType, AttrValue)
```

(Can also be done when `create table`.)

Comment: Hi jarlh,  but with this we will have constraints on attr2 and attr3 as well. I only want unique constraint for attr2 values.

Comment: That's much trickier. I don't think Postgresql has any built-in functionality to do that. I'd consider a trigger based solution.

Comment: @user1298426 Something like `create unique index idx_tablename_attr1 on tablename(AttrValue) where AttrType = 'attr1';` Look for [partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createindex.html)